# Dynamic Navigation using Vue Router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, router

I want to setup my Vue App to use a linear navigation structure to arrange the final html documents that I will be serving via *iFrame*.

```
.
├── School
│   ├── SQL
|   |   ├── SQL Basics
|   |   ├── SQL Intermediate
|   |   ├── SQL Advanced
|   |   └── ...
│   ├── Python
|   |   ├── Python Basics
|   |   ├── Python Data Structures
|   |   ├── Python Classes
|   |   ├── Python Advanced
|   |   └── ...
|   └──...   
└── ...
```

The current way I have been able to achieve with this structure is to create a Component for *School*, one for *SQL* and one for *Python* and have list rendering Cards for navigation. You can see that this will get tedious if I expand in the future.

I want to improve the structure to have just one Cards component dynamically generating the route and the navigation cards and the data being fed from the `Vuex` Store.

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/j1w1wok365)

Answer (score 0):

You can inject additional routes at any time, You don't have to declare up front.

You could make use of **router.addRoutes** so you can iterate your object of content and generate the routes on application **beforeMount** or **beforeCreate** where you would do **this.$router.addRoutes(...)**.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeMount

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeCreate

https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-addroutes